# Cocos2d schedule method in NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

It's me again with a Cocos2D problem. :-D

I create the main character of my upcoming game as a sublclass of NSObject. This class has a property for the Sprite, Spritesheet and all that stuff. But now I have the following problem.

I want to schedule a method for animating the sprite. That action which should be scheduled every second. But because I'm using a subclass of NSObject to hold all my data, I cannot use `[self schedule:@selector(action:) interval:1.0]`. Is there another way? I don't want to use NSTimer, because I then can't you the CCDirector anymore to break the game. 
It'd really be helpful if you could help me. :-D

Sandro Meier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to skin that cat, but here are a few:

- Subclass CCNode instead of NSObject and call [yourClass schedule: interval:]
- Expose a simplified selector that internally calls [self.sprite schedule: interval:]
- Externally call [yourClass.sprite schedule: interval:]
- Internally call [self.sprite schedule: interval:]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with the first way. But your 3th and 4th method don't work, because the methods I want to schedule are not in the CCSprite. They are in my NSObject Subclass. ;-)

Comment: Ah, well it was just a guideline since I didn't know what you were actually trying to schedule.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

```
//SomeObject.h
@interface SomeObject : NSObject 
{
}
-(void) initObject;
@end    

//SomeObject.m
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "SomeObject.h"
@implementation SomeObject

-(id) init
{
    return [super init];
}

-(void) initObject
{
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleUpdateForTarget:self priority:0 paused:NO];
}

-(void) update:(ccTime) dt
{
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleUpdateForTarget:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Also look at this

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(ping) forTarget:self interval:2.f paused:NO];

-(void) ping
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't need it anymore. But I think it's good to have this answer here.